# How to show user location without button click if permission is already given

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, location, reload

I am facing some problem with HTML geolocation. I actually want to display the current location everytime the page is visited when the user has given permission..

I am able to show location in the form of lat and long but only when I click on button even if the user has given permission.. How can I show it without clicking on the button and on page reload..

Sidenote: Just like Swiggy or Zomato which shows location everytime we open the app.

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}
function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
function showError(error) {
  switch(error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
break;
}}
```

Comment: Show your code that tries to do it.

Comment: so what is your code?

Comment: Check the code now!

Answer (score 0):

The simple way would be to call the `getLocation()` on `window.load`. You could also attach it to the `<body>` tag like this `<body onload="getLocation()">`.

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

window.onload = getLocation;

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {    
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showError(error) {
  switch(error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
break;
}}
```

Comment: @AbhimanyuSharma What is not working about it? Is there an error? Is nothing happening? Please be specific.

Comment: Nothing is happening!